# Terraform to push file to github with content from Consul key/value store

Tags: git, github, terraform, devops, consul

I am trying to get the content of a key on Consul (which is a json object) to convert into the content of a file that I need to push to Github using Consul-Terraform-Sync. The path on Consul is composed of a UUID which is provided as a meta var from the triggering service.

```
data "consul_keys" "json_file_key" {
  for_each = var.services

  key {
    name    = "json_file"
    path    = "path/with/${lookup(each.value.meta, "uuid")}/to/json_file"
  }
}

resource "github_repository_file" "repo_on_github" {
  for_each = var.services

  repository          = "my-repo"
  branch              = "main"
  file                = "path/to/json/on/github/repo"
  content             = jsondecode(data.consul_keys.json_file_key[each.key].id)
  commit_message      = "Managed by Terraform - UUID: ${lookup(each.value.meta, "uuid")}"
}
```

Which yields the error:

```
Call to function "jsondecode" failed: unexpected EOF.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You are missing `for_each` in the `github_repository_file` reesource.

Comment: @MarkoE I have edited the example code, same error.